# React Apollo Client: Pagination and fetch data on button click

Tags: reactjs, graphql, apollo-client, react-apollo

I am new to Apollo Client and want to implement pagination. My code looks like this:

I am using RickandMorty endpoint for this (https://rickandmortyapi.com/graphql)

`useCharacters.tsx`

```
import { useQuery, gql } from '@apollo/client';

const GET_ALL_CHARACTERS = gql`
    query GetCharacters($page: Int) {
        characters(page: $page) {
            info {
                count
                pages
            }
            results {
                id
                name
            }
        }
    }
`;

export const useCharacters = (page: number = 1) => {
    const { data, loading, error } = useQuery(GET_ALL_CHARACTERS, { variables: { page } });

    return { data, loading, error };
};
```

`App.tsx`

```
export const App = () => {
    const { data, loading, error } = useCharacters(1);

    const nextPage = () => {
      const { data, loading, error } = useCharacters(2);
    };

    return (
        <>
            {loading ? (
                <div> Loading... </div>
            ) : error ? (
                <div>Error</div>
            ) : (
            <>
                <CharacterList data={data.characters.results} />
                <div onClick={nextPage}> Next </div>
            </>
    );
};
```

It is fetching data properly the first time but I want to fetch new data when `Next` button is clicked on page 2.

I know I can't call `useQuery()` in a method like this as hooks cannot be called inside a block and also the `data`, `error`, and `loading` won't be accessible outside.

How can I fix this issue? I tried googling it but could not find any help related to this.

Comment: You'd use fetchMore. Apollo pagination docs https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/v2/data/pagination/ . Tip - move your loading / error checks into their own return - it's easier to digest.  if(error) return <div>error</div>; if(loading) return <div>loading</div>;  return (<></>)

Comment: Thanks @SeanW. I will check it out

Answer (score 1):

This might help other developers who are new to Apollo Client and will save them time.

`fetchMore()` can be used for pagination with Apollo Client.

`useCharacters.tsx`

```
export const useCharacters = (page: number = 1, name: string = '') => {
    const { data, loading, error, fetchMore } = useQuery(GET_ALL_CHARACTERS, {
        variables: { page, name },
        notifyOnNetworkStatusChange: true,   // to show loader
    });

    return { data, loading, error, fetchMore };  // returning fetchMore
};
```

`App.tsx`

```
export const App = () => {
    const { data, loading, error, fetchMore } = useCharacters(1);

    const nextPage = () => {
      /* You can call the returned fetchMore() here and pass the next page number. 
         updateQuery() simply updates your data to the newly fetched records otherwise return previous records
      */
      fetchMore({
            variables: {
                page: 2,
            },
            updateQuery: (prev, { fetchMoreResult }) => {
                if (!fetchMoreResult) return prev;
                return fetchMoreResult;
            },
        });
    };

    return (
        <>
            {loading ? (
                <div> Loading... </div>
            ) : error ? (
                <div>Error</div>
            ) : (
            <>
                <CharacterList data={data.characters.results} />
                <div onClick={nextPage}> Next </div>
            </>
    );
};
```